# Wamp gives ' Exception in module wampmanager.exe at 000F15A0 '

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I installed **WAMP Server** as successful. But When I run that, It's show following Warning,

[image]

Here Even I click anyone option, It's gives following Error,

[image]

Where is Mistake?

What to Do?

**Note:**

OS is Windows 7 64-bit

Wamp2.2

Comment: Are you uploading any images to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Cause and Best Solution see: http://hints.steptoinstall.com/exception-in-module-wampmanager-exe-at-000f15a0.html

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have the latest version of both of these Microsoft C++ Redistributable runtime libraries.
Incorrect or missing version of the C++ 2008 SP1 runtime is the most likely cause of your situation.

The 2008 Redist is used by wampmanager
The 2010 Redist is used by Apache

FOR WAMP 32bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328

FOR WAMP 64bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523

Comment: +1 Thanks helped me.  What's sad is they could either install this themselves, or detect that it's not installed (either at installation or runtime) and let you know.

Comment: Yes, unless you dont want to do that for some reason. Then you would be swearing at them for doing it without permission. They do give a warning message when you download the install, but most people dont read it.

Comment: I am getting the same issue and this is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds a little wierd but do check your installation.

Install the 64-bit Windows OS and keep the WAMP Server's 64-bit installation as it is. --OR--
Install the 32-bit version of WAMP Server on the current Windows 32-bit OS.

Comment: Its actually quite happy running WAMPServer 32bit on a 64bit Windows, and as there are still quite a few PHP extensions that have not been converted to 64bit its the safer option. Also all the WAMP ADDONS are actually still only 32bit, so if you want multiple versions of Apache/MySQ/PHP the 32bit route is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

The error with exception 000F15A0 because of windows runtime problem go and install 
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=15336)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps your error would be ended

1) Check your system either is 32bit or 64

2) download the microsoft visual c++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable edition
download (http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/d/9/dd9a82d0-52ef-40db-8dab-795376989c03/vcredist_x86.exe)

3) if you downloaded above package, then download the wamp server according to your system compatability like mine is 32 bit so downloaded from
(http://netassist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wampserver/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b.exe"microsoft")

4) All don!!!